# остановка анимации по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Вечер добрый! Подскажите как сделать остановку анимации по нажатию на кнопку stop и кто может оцените код, может что-то нужно изменить? Забыл добавить, чтобы и очищался экран от квадратов

```js
function play() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
 
function animate() {  
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
  var score = document.getElementById('score');
  var count = 1;

  function Square (x, y, w, h) {
   this.x = Math.random() * 620;
   this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
   this.r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

    this.rgba = "rgba(" + this.r + ", " + this.g + ", " + this.b + ", 1)";

    this.draw = function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.rgba;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
      this.update();
    }

    this.update = function() {
      this.y += Math.random() * 3;
    }
  }
  
  var squares = [];

  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth);
    for(i = 0; i < squares.length; i++)
        squares[i].draw();
    update();
  }

  function update() {
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      squares[i].update();
    }
  }

  setInterval(function(){
    
    squares.push(new Square(0, 0, 20, 20))
  },1000);

  setInterval(draw, 20);
    
    var isCursorInSquares = function(x, y, squares) {
    return  x > squares.x && x < squares.x + squares.w + 8 && 
            y > squares.y && y < squares.y + squares.h + 20;
    }

  canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;

    for(var i = squares.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
      if(isCursorInSquares(x, y, squares[i])) { 
        delete squares.splice(i, 1);
        score.innerHTML = count++;
      } 
    }
  }

  var clearSquares = function() {
    score.innerHTML = count = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Qualium Systems Javascript test task </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <style>
      canvas {        
        background: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button onclick="play()" "> Start </button>
      <button onclick="stop()"> Stop </button>
      <span> Score: <span id="score"> 0 </span> </span>
    </div>
    <canvas width="640" height="480" id="canvas"></canvas>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно `setInterval()` идентифицировать через переменные, а в методе `stop()`, использовать `clearInterval()`, чтобы остановить работу `setInterval()`

```js
var animate1Interval, animate2Interval, canvas, ctx;

function stop()  {
     clearInterval(animate1Interval);
     clearInterval(animate2Interval);
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth);
}

function play() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
 
function animate() {  
  var score = document.getElementById('score');
  var count = 1;

  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function Square (x, y, w, h) {
   this.x = Math.random() * 620;
   this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
   this.r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

    this.rgba = "rgba(" + this.r + ", " + this.g + ", " + this.b + ", 1)";

    this.draw = function() {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.rgba;
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
      this.update();
    }

    this.update = function() {
      this.y += Math.random() * 3;
    }
  }
  
  var squares = [];

  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth);
    for(i = 0; i < squares.length; i++)
        squares[i].draw();
    update();
  }

  function update() {
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      squares[i].update();
    }
  }

  animate1Interval = setInterval(function(){
    
    squares.push(new Square(0, 0, 20, 20))
  },1000);

  animate2Interval = setInterval(draw, 20);
    
    var isCursorInSquares = function(x, y, squares) {
    return  x > squares.x && x < squares.x + squares.w + 8 && 
            y > squares.y && y < squares.y + squares.h + 20;
    }

  canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;

    for(var i = squares.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
      if(isCursorInSquares(x, y, squares[i])) { 
        delete squares.splice(i, 1);
        score.innerHTML = count++;
      } 
    }
  }

  var clearSquares = function() {
    score.innerHTML = count = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Qualium Systems Javascript test task </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <style>
      canvas {        
        background: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button onclick="play()" "> Start </button>
      <button onclick="stop()"> Stop </button>
      <span> Score: <span id="score"> 0 </span> </span>
    </div>
    <canvas width="640" height="480" id="canvas"></canvas>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Благодорю! Буду пробовать.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы очищался экран от квадратов?

Comment: @ArtyomSapsay добавил в код, возможно лучше переменные `canvas`, `ctx` вывести за пределы `animate()`, чтобы в `stop` все заново не определять, в коде не стал так делать, чтобы не запутать

Comment: Если выношу переменные за пределы 'animate()', выдаёт ошибку 'canvas is null'.

Comment: @ArtyomSapsay поправил, чтобы не было `null`, когда выносите полностью `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')` за пределы `animate()`, нужно весь код обернуть в событие `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){}` так как не успевает DOM прогрузиться